# deleting tabs one space at a time

Tags: python, tabs, vim

How do I configure vim so that I can delete a tab one space at a time rather than the entire tab?  I often want to do this when I'm trying to align multiple tests for an if statement.  In the below example, condition3 is aligned as I want and condition2 is off by one space due to the tab.

```
if condition1 or \
    condition2 or \
   condition3:
    do something
```

I'm using vim 7.2.108 on OSX 10.6.7 and have the following mode line in my code file:

```
# ex: tabstop=4 softtabstop=1 shiftwidth=4 expandtab:
```

FWIW, this mode line does allow me to use the arrow keys to navigate through a tab one space at a time.

Update:  Here's the changes I've made to the example vimrc file from Bram Mooleanar:

```
map z :w<cr>
map q :q!<cr>
map m :make<cr>

set expandtab
set shiftwidth=4
set tabstop=4

set bs=2        " backspace over anything in insert mode
set showmatch       " display the matching bracket of the pair
set nowrap      " don't wrap line to fit window
set showmatch       " show matching paren, bracket, or brace
set ruler       " show current cursor position at bottom
set incsearch       " show next match as you type in search pattern
set ignorecase
set smartcase

syntax on       " enable syntax highlighting
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would just hit `x` in normal mode to delete a single character. I'll also point out the great indent/python.vim [script](http://www.vim.org/scripts/script.php?script_id=974) by Eric McSween. It doesn't really change the backspace behavior, but it allows you to do something more in line with PEP8---using Python's implied line continuation using parentheses. With the script, the code above would look like

```
if (condition1 or
    condition2 or
    condition3):
    do something
```

Comment: Thanks, Sam.  I'll try your suggestions.  Even simply enclosing the conditions within parens would solve my problem.

Answer (score 4):

I would say put this in your .vimrc file:

```
set expandtab
```

Which basically turns tabs into spaces when you hit the tab key.

Comment: Hi Dhaivat, in starting with a clean vimrc and test file to try your suggestion, I found my problem: when I have the softtabstop set, it prevented me from deleting a tab one space at a time.  However, when I readded the vimrc file that I had been using (an example one that Bram Moolenaar wrote), my problem returns.

Answer (score 0):

It looks like the problem is that you are using a mix of tabs and spaces to manage alignment.
In most environments where there are many people working on the same files it is recommended that *only* spaces or only tabs are used.
That said you could map a key to delete the tab character and insert 3 spaces in its place by adding the following to your vimrc.

```
map <F1> s   <ESC>
```

If you want to do it in insert mode:

```
imap <F1> <BS>
```

*note that there are three spaces after the ">"

Comment: Thanks, Sam.  I don't know how my tabs and spaces are getting mixed up, but I'll experiment with these vim key mappings.